# Can @Bind be used with enums and other arbitrary types using JDBI?

Tags: java, mysql, dropwizard, jdbi

Does JDBI support binding of enum types via annotation?

For example, assuming a DAO that included a method:

```
@SqlQuery("select count(*) from answer a where a.foo = :foo")
Long someSqlQuery(@Bind("foo") Foo foo);
```

And, `foo` equal to `Foo.BAR`, could I expect a query:

```
select count(*) from answer a where a.foo = 'BAR'
```

If so, is `toString()` utilized to determine what is substituted?

Further, Does JDBI allow for using `@Bind` with any type that extends `Object`?  And again, if so, is `toString()` used?

Comment: As a follow on comment, my experience using 2.5.1 is that `Enum` does behave in the way I describe above.  That said, I've also seen some strange behavior, around this, possibly because of conflicting JDBI versions locally.  I was hoping someone can point me to the documentation related to this feature (I only see documentation demonstrating `Strings`, primitive types, and `Date`) and an indication of which version allowed for using `@Bind` with `enum`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/blob/4c2eeb3792005beaabfc67b2f479dc2ee1dd3d22/src/main/java/org/skife/jdbi/v2/EnumArgument.java) `Enum.name()` is used, not `toString()`

If an object is bound, jdbi uses `setObject(Object object)` of the jdbc driver you're using. In my experience with PostgreSQL for example, it successfully binds `Map`s to `hstore` and arrays to postgreSQL `array`s because that's what PostgreSQL's jdbc driver does.

If you want to handle a specific kind of objects in a specific way, you can implement `ArgumentFactory`s (for which there seems to be no documentation but an example here in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022452/does-jdbi-accept-uuid-parameters)) or [BinderFactory](http://jdbi.org/sql_object_api_argument_binding/)s (which I've just discovered now.)

Comment: Quick note: You'll need JDBI 2.56 or later to successfully bind Enums.  It wasn't until this point that `EnumArgument` was added as one of the default `Argument` types.  So prior to this you'll need to create the functionality yourself be creating an `EnumArgument` and an `EnumArgumentFactory`.

Comment: Ah yes. Actually, before that I had a lot of `getEnumName()` hacks to get around it which I have removed later.

Answer (score 1):

To address your "arbitrary types" question, you can implement a [`BinderFactory`](http://jdbi.org/apidocs/org/skife/jdbi/v2/sqlobject/BinderFactory.html) to bind to anything you want.

```
@BindingAnnotation(UserBinder.UserBinderFactory.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface UserBinder {
    public static class UserBinderFactory implements BinderFactory {

        @Override
        public Binder build(Annotation annotation) {
            return new Binder<UserBinder, User>() {
                @Override
                public void bind(SQLStatement<?> q, UserBinder bind, User arg) {
                    q.bind("userId", arg.getUserId());
                    q.bind("uuid", arg.getUuid());
                    q.bind("openId", arg.getOpenId());
                    q.bind("givenName", arg.getGivenName());
                    // etc.
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

This is most useful if you have complex types that you want stored in a particular way, e.g. binary data, or collections that you want turned into CSVs or only stored in separate mapping tables. Then you use your new fancy binder like so:

```
@SqlUpdate(
        "INSERT INTO user (openId,givenName,uuid," +
        // etc.
        ") VALUES (:openId,:givenName,:uuid" +
        // etc.
        ")"
)
public abstract int createUser(
        @UserBinder User user
);
```

You can also use an `@BindBean` annotation, which will automatically look up fields on an object by the bind parameter name (e.g. it can map a query placeholder `":userId"` to the `getUserId()` method).

Comment: Nice answer, but providing an example that doesn't actually do anything beyond what the default `BindBean` implementation does is a bit confusing.